# three.js Plane-Plane intersection point

Tags: javascript, three.js

three.js Plane() object has its .intersectLine() method.

I need to retrieve the intersection point of three Planes. A Method called .intersectPlanes(plane_A, plane_B) would be perfect, but is not implemented.

Do you know how to get the intersection point instead?

Thank you!

Comment: There can be many cases with [three planes](http://www.emathematics.net/posreltresplanos.php).

Comment: If it doesn't exist, create it. Create a new function, `THREE.Plane.prototype.intersectPlanesPoint`. Have it intersect two of them to get a line, and then intersect the third with that line. Of course you'll need to account for the non-point cases called out by @prisoner849. When you have such a method ready, contact the three.js team to see if such a convenience function would be helpful--your code could end up in three.js!

Comment: Good idea, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i have already answered this question in another post:

[Finding the intersection point of a bundle of planes (3) in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597503/finding-the-intersection-point-of-a-bundle-of-planes-3-in-three-js)
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597503/finding-the-intersection-point-of-a-bundle-of-planes-3-in-three-js`